# Ansible include_tasks with loop failed to check when condition

Tags: loops, ansible

I want to include tasks based on the condition set inside the task.

```
tasks:
- name: SET INIT STATUS
  set_facts:
    passed: true

- name: INCLUDE TASKS WITH LOOP
  include_tasks: update_status.yml
  loop: [1, 2, 3]
  when: passed
```

update_status.yml:

```
- name: OUTPUT THE STATUS
  debug: msg="ITEM: {{item}} has status {{passed}}"
- name: UPDATE the Status
  set_fact:
    passed: false
```

What I expected that it will only run once for item 1 because after it runs, it will change the status to false and then it failed the condition check. But it actually run 3 time so looks like it does not check the status during the loop again.

Here is the output

```
TASK: [SET INIT STATUS]
ok: [localhost]

TASK: [INCLUDE TASKS WITH LOOP]
included: simple.yml for localhost
included: simple.yml for localhost
included: simple.yml for localhost

TASK: [OUTPUT THE STATUS]
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": ITEM 1 has status True
}

TASK: [UPDATE the Status]
ok: [localhost]

TASK: [OUTPUT THE STATUS]
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": ITEM 2 has status False
}

TASK: [UPDATE the Status]
ok: [localhost]

TASK: [OUTPUT THE STATUS]
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": ITEM 3 has status False
}

TASK: [UPDATE the Status]
ok: [localhost]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Q: ***"Loop failed to check when condition."***

A: Quoting from [Applying ‘when’ to roles, imports, and includes](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.9/user_guide/playbooks_conditionals.html#applying-when-to-roles-imports-and-includes):

> When a conditional is used with include_* tasks instead of imports, it is applied only to the include task itself and not to any other tasks within the included file(s).

Given the file

```yaml
shell> cat update_status.yml
- debug:
    msg: "item: {{ item }} has status {{ passed }}"
- set_fact:
    passed: false
```

the below play

```yaml
shell> cat pb1.yml
- hosts: all

  tasks:

    - set_fact:
        passed: true

    - include_tasks: update_status.yml
      loop: [1, 2, 3]
      when: passed
```

gives (abridged to the debug output) limited to single host test_11

```yaml
shell> ansible-playbook -l test_11 pb1.yml
  ...
  msg: 'item: 1 has status True'
  msg: 'item: 2 has status False'
  msg: 'item: 3 has status False'
  ...
```

**Parameter apply**

Use the parameter [apply](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/include_tasks_module.html#parameter-apply) if you want to apply the condition to the included tasks. Quoting:

> Accepts a hash of task keywords (e.g. tags, become) that will be applied to the tasks within the include.

Then, the below play

```yaml
shell> cat pb2.yml
- hosts: all

  tasks:

    - set_fact:
        passed: true

    - include_tasks:
        file: update_status.yml
        apply:
          when: passed
      loop: [1, 2, 3]
      when: passed
```

(limited to single host test_11) will display only item 1. Items 2 and 3 will be skipped

```yaml
shell> ansible-playbook -l test_11 pb2.yml
  ...
  msg: 'item: 1 has status True'
  ...
```

---

This makes the included tasks effectively look like:

```yaml
- debug:
    msg: "item: {{ item }} has status {{ passed }}"
  when: passed
- set_fact:
    passed: false
  when: passed
```

---

**Block**

Quoting the Note from [Grouping tasks with blocks](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_blocks.html#grouping-tasks-with-blocks):

> All tasks in a block, including the ones included through *include_role*, inherit directives applied at the block level.

It seems this works also for *include_tasks*. Applying the condition to a block and putting the include into this block has the same effect as using the parameter *apply* in the include. The below play gives the same result as pb2.yml

```yaml
shell> cat pb3.yml
- hosts: all

  tasks:

    - set_fact:
        passed: true

    - block:
        - include_tasks: update_status.yml
          loop: [1, 2, 3]
      when: passed
```

---

See: [Change insertion order of apply block to not affect the include_X task itself #44912](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/pull/44912)

Notes:

- At the moment (Ansible version 2.9) it is not possible to break a loop in Ansible.
- It's a good idea to explicitly cast Boolean bare variables in conditionals `when: passed|bool`. See [Bare variables in conditionals](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/porting_guides/porting_guide_2.8.html#bare-variables-in-conditionals).

---

There are 2 syntax errors in the question:

- "ERROR! couldn't resolve module/action 'set_facts'". There is no module `set_facts`.

Correct syntax

```yaml
- name: SET INIT STATUS
  set_fact:
    passed: true
```

- "Syntax Error while loading YAML.  mapping values are not allowed in this context ... - name: OUTPUT THE STATUS\n  debug: msg="ITEM: {{item}} has status {{passed}}"

Correct syntax

```yaml
- name: OUTPUT THE STATUS
  debug:
    msg: "ITEM: {{ item }} has status {{ passed }}"
```

Comment: `At the same time, the condition when: passed, applied to the loop, decides whether the loop will start or not. Once the loop is started it will not take the condition into consideration anymore and will run all iterations` - this is patently not true, when `include_tasks` is not used - please check the documentation [here](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_loops.html#iterating-over-a-list-of-hashes) and try it yourself.

Comment: Right. I updated the answer. Thank you for the comment!

Answer (score 2):

After trying different approach, i was able to achieve what i want by putting the loop inside a block.

```
- name: LOOP WITH INCLUDE_TASK INSIDE BLOCK
  block:
    - name: LOOP WITH INCLUDE_TASK
      include_tasks: simple.yml
      loop: [1, 2, 3]
  when: passed
```

And here is the result

```
TASK [SET passed] ******************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK [LOOP WITH INCLUDE_TASK] ******************************************************************************************
included: /home/richard/samples/simple.yml for localhost
included: /home/richard/samples/simple.yml for localhost
included: /home/richard/samples/simple.yml for localhost

TASK [SHOW THE STATUS] ******************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": "Item 1 has status True"
}

TASK [CHANGE THE STATUS] ******************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK [SHOW THE STATUS] ******************************************************************************************
skipping: [localhost]

TASK [CHANGE THE STATUS] ******************************************************************************************
skipping: [localhost]

TASK [SHOW THE STATUS] ******************************************************************************************
skipping: [localhost]

TASK [CHANGE THE STATUS] ******************************************************************************************
skipping: [localhost]
```

Comment: Thank you. FYI: This is equivalent to putting `when: passed` on each of the tasks in `simple.yml`.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're hitting a fun Jinja side effect. Try this for your conditional.

`when: passed|bool`

This will ensure its being evaluated as a bones expression.